# How to Call a Variable from a Class to Fla?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've class file named Meters.as I need call an array variable from Meters.as to main fla.

My class file is located at here: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/336578/

Here's my code:

```
var meterArr:Meters = new Meters();
trace(meterArr.meterArray[0, 0]);
```

This code gives me error 1119. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

import Meters. If meterArray is a static variable in Meters (i see that it is), that's all you'll have to do.

By the way, you've gone to a lot of trouble to fill each slot in your array with `" "`. Have you considered doin it automatically, with just a few lines of code, in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

in your class write your varible like this:

```
public static var my_array:Array = new Array
```

the key code is that two words behind your var in your class `public static` 
for calling your class you can do it like this:

```
my_class.my_array
```